# what is actually happening when converting Pandas Dataframe to Spark Dataframe

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I understand that when user call `toPandas` on Spark DataFrame,
Spark execute all the transformation, aggregates data and store the result in memory on a client machine.

(as described in [What is the Spark DataFrame method `toPandas` actually doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226210/what-is-the-spark-dataframe-method-topandas-actually-doing))

Does that mean, given that I have pandas DataFrame, if I create Spark DataFrame using this (any local) pandas DataFrame, Spark partitions(?) and distributes(?) Pandas DataFrame and returns Spark DataFrame (which is basically RDD that is immutable and start keeping track of transformation applied to DataFrame) ???

I just want to understand what's happening behind the scene

Thank you

Comment: Well indeed that panda's dataframe will be stores locally on your driver, so you lose all the parallelism etc. Indeed, your application may crash

Comment: ya I understand that, but the post is asking what happens for the other direction