# Allocating clusters to data points stored in spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, euclidean-distance

I have two spark DataFrames.

**schema DataFrame A (stores cluster centroids):**

```
cluster_id, dim1_pos, dim2_pos, dim3_pos, ..., dimN_pos
```

**schema of DataFrame B (data points):**

```
entity_id, dim1_pos, dim2_pos, dim3_pos, ..., dimN_pos
```

There are around 100 rows in DataFrame A, meaning I have 100 cluster centroids. I need to map each entity in DataFrame B to a cluster which is closest (in terms of euclidean distance).

How should I do this?

I want a DataFrame with schema: **entity_id,cluster_id** as my final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using VectorAssembler to put all the dimX columns' values into a single column (for each dataframe).

Once this was done, I simply used combinations of UDF to get to answer.

```
import numpy as np

featureCols = [dim1_pos, dim2_pos, ..., dimN_pos]
vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=featureCols, outputCol="features")
dfA = vecAssembler.transform(dfA)
dfB = vecAssembler.transform(dfB)

def distCalc(a, b):
    return np.sum(np.square(a-b))

def closestPoint(point_x, centers):
    udf_dist = udf(lambda x: distCalc(x, point_x), DoubleType())
    centers = centers.withColumn('distance',udf_dist(centers.features))
    centers.registerTempTable('t1')
    bestIndex = #write a query to get minimum distance from centers df
    return bestIndex


udf_closestPoint = udf(lambda x: closestPoint(x, dfA), IntegerType())
dfB = dfB.withColumn('cluster_id',udf_closestPoint(dfB.features))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the Spark dataframe is not huge you can use `toPandas()` to turn it inti pandas dataframe and use `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist()` (read [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) for more info)

**Example Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

cluster = DataFrame({'cluster_id': [1, 2, 3, 7],
                'dim1_pos': [201, 204, 203, 204],
                'dim2_pos':[55, 40, 84, 31]})
entity = DataFrame({'entity_id': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                'dim1_pos': [201, 204, 203],
                'dim2_pos':[55, 40, 84]})
cluster.set_index('cluster_id',inplace=True)
entity.set_index('entity_id',inplace=True)

result_metric= cdist(cluster, entity, metric='euclidean')

result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_metric,index=cluster.index.values,columns=entity.index.values)
print result_df

            A          B          C
1    0.000000  15.297059  29.068884
2   15.297059   0.000000  44.011362
3   29.068884  44.011362   0.000000
7   24.186773   9.000000  53.009433
```

Then you can use `idxmin()` with specify the **axis** to find the minimum pair from each row of the metric,like below:

```
# get the min. pair
result = DataFrame(result_df.idxmin(axis=1,skipna=True))
# turn the index value into column
result.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
# rename and order the columns
result.columns = ['cluster_id','entity_id']
result = result.reindex(columns=['entity_id','cluster_id'])
print result

  entity_id  cluster_id
0         A           1
1         B           2
2         C           3
3         B           7
```

Comment: Will this work for spark dataframes? The dataframes in question are spark. If I convert to pandas dataframe, will it not bring the entire df into single machine?

Comment: you can apply ``toPandas()`` to convert a spark dataframe into pandas dataframe perfectly. More info read [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html). Cheers:)

Comment: But the amount of data is huge, converting into a pandas data frame will create an in-memory data frame. Too much to handle for local memory. Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226210/what-is-the-spark-dataframe-method-topandas-actually-doing

Comment: I am not familiar with Scipy working with PySpark dataframe. So, maybe you need to calculate the euclidean distance with ``udf`` in ``pyspark.sql.functions``.

Comment: Yeah, I converted both the data frame's dimX-columns into a single column using VectorAssembler and then used Euclidean distance by UDF. :)