# What if i write Pandas code on PySpark by using PySpark toPandas() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I'm not very familiar with the PySpark library, which is why I prefer pandas. Regardless, I will utilise the toPandas() function in Pyspark, write the code in pandas, and convert back the pandas dataframe to a Spark dataframe. Will the time complexity change if we use the toPandas() function that we're importing from PySpark, write the pandas code, and execute it? Will it differ from the original PySpark code, and will its time complexity be altered?

**For instance, if I were to write df.show() and df.head(), would the compilation time be the same or different?**

Comment: It all depends on quite a lot of factors:
- Usecase
- Current spark setup(version of spark).

Few helpful links:

https://www.databricks.com/blog/2021/10/04/pandas-api-on-upcoming-apache-spark-3-2.html
https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29233999/2986344

Comment: Collecting to Pandas tends to have a limit depending on the JVM Heap size. It's best if you keep the operations on a Spark DataFrame. You can use [Fugue](https://fugue-tutorials.readthedocs.io/tutorials/quick_look/ten_minutes.html) for your use case to write code in Pandas and apply it per Spark partition easily.